# A simple situtation I am facing on sending a char as an instruction

Tags: matlab, char

This comes as a much bigger problem, but it can be exemplified using a very stupid example. I am using Matlab. Suppose `A= 1:4`and that `B = 'A==3'` (yes, B is a char that contains A in its expression). This seems like a very stupid question, I want to be able to evaluate `A(A==3)` using something like `A(B)`. Is this possible?

As I am doing it for 2^N different combinations with N being an integer, I want to know if it is possible to evaluate it in this way.

Comment: Matlab (sorry, I just realized I did not explicitly stated this).

Comment: `eval(['A(' B ')'])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are really stuck with `B = 'A==3'`, then you can use `eval` to get the mask:

```
A(eval(B))
```

Or eval the whole statement with `eval(sprintf('A(%s)',B))`.

Not sure what you mean by combinations.

Comment: What I meant with combinations is that this evaluation comes within a loop so that for N = 3, I have to evaluate 2^N = 8 different statements. It was a clarification just to state that I can't do it by hand.

Comment: @MathUser Gotcha.  Glad this helped.